# what should be the value of the estimator parameter in learning_curve function in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, knn

I am trying to make a learning curve and the algorithm I want to use is knn algorithm. for this what should be the value of estimator. Its possible values or options are not in documentation(and I am not sure if it should be there).

here is my code-

```
features = ['age','sex','cp','trestbps','chol','fbs','restecg','thalach','exang','oldpeak','slope','ca','thal']
target = 'num'

train_size, train_scores, validation_scores = learning_curve(estimator = KNN(), x=dataset[features], y=dataset[target], train_size=train_sizes, cv=5, scoring='confusion_matrix')
```

error is - KNN() is not defined(which is obvious why). but my question is if I want to use knn algorithm what should be it value.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "what should be it value"?

Comment: what should be the value of estimator parameter for using knearest neighbor algorithm

Comment: what should be the value of estimator parameter for using K nearest neighbor algorithm

Comment: Well the values completely depends on your task and data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`learning curve` docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.learning_curve.html):

> **estimator** : object type that implements the “fit” and “predict” methods

So, if you are in a regression setting, you should use

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
# define the no. of nearest neighbors k
train_size, train_scores, validation_scores = learning_curve(estimator = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=k), [...])
```

while if you are in a classification setting, you should use

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
# define the no. of nearest neighbors k
train_size, train_scores, validation_scores = learning_curve(estimator = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k), [...])
```

where of course in both cases you should also define the number of nearest neighbors `k`.

The general idea is that in the `estimator` argument you can use any scikit-learn available algorithm that implements `fit` and `predist` methods, as clearly mentioned in the documentation (link provided above).